# PyDLL does not work across different Python versions

Tags: python, c++

I am using PyDLL function to bind DLL to Python.

From Python side:

```
import ctypes as _ct
_path = _parent_path(__file__) / "scisuit_pybind"
pydll = _ct.PyDLL(str(_path))

pydll.c_root_bisect.argtypes = [_ct.py_object, _ct.c_double, _ct.c_double, _ct.c_double, _ct.c_int, _ct.c_char_p, _ct.c_bool]
pydll.c_root_bisect.restype = _ct.py_object
```

And from C++ side:

```
#define EXTERN \
    extern "C" DLLPYBIND

EXTERN PyObject * c_root_bisect(PyObject * FuncObj,
    double a,
    double b,
    double tol = 1e-5,
    int maxiter = 100,
    const char* method = "bf",
    bool modified = false);
```

Cases are:

1. **Works:** Compile the DLL with Python 3.10.6 and run it with Python 3.10.6. **Fails**  when run with Python 3.11.
2. **Works** Compile the DLL with Python 3.11 and run with 3.11. **Fails** when run with Python 3.10.

**Error:** *self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)*

What am I missing?

---

**EDIT 1**:

A quick fix (maybe not the best one) is to build DLLs (affected one is small, around 170 KB) for 3.x versions (currently I made them for 3.10 and 3.11) and then from Python side:

```
_DLLname= "scisuit_pybind"
if sys.version_info.minor == 10:
    _DLLname= "scisuit_pybind310"

_path = _parent_path(__file__) / _DLLname
```

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. Python application binary interface (ABI) only stable within a major version, e.g. anything built for 3.10.1 will also work for 3.10.2. But something built for 3.x0.y0 won't work for 3.x1.y1 when x0 isn't equal to x1.

See, e.g., https://peps.python.org/pep-3149/

> Extension modules compiled for different Python major versions are incompatible with each other due to changes in the ABI.

The same happens with Python modules built with pybind11.

Comment: I have added and Edit section where I solved the problem. I realized that for example numpy releases with different file names (numpy-1.26.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl) for each ABI. I am using toml file and I could not achieve that as all file names end up being `projectname-py3-any-none.whl`